# "If I didn't give it to you" vs. "If I had't given it to you"

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

Is this second conditional or third conditional with didn't? in the case of the latter **if I didn't** would mean **if I hadn't**. Is that correct?

Guy 1: (*..Give the toy to Guy 2..*)

Guy 1: "You're giving it to me!? Thank you!."

Guy 2: "Just protecting myself. ..If **I didn't** give it to you, then
 walking the streets at night **would be** scary."

Comment: Minor correction (possible typo).  Your subject line or title is incorrect.  You can't say "If I hadn't give" - it would need to be "if I hadn't given".  Whereas "did" and "didn't" are followed by the bare infinitive ("give" here), "had" and "hadn't" are followed by the past participle ("given" here) when forming the past perfect.

Answer (score 1):

With "*didn't*", you would use the *second* conditional.

The **second conditional** consists of a subordinate IF clause (**simple past**) plus a main clause in the **conditional**. E.g. *If I didn't eat so much, I wouldn't feel sick.* ( http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/second-conditional.html and http://www.grammar.cl/english/second-conditional.htm )

The **third conditional** consists of a subordinate IF clause (**past perfect**) plus a main clause in the **conditional perfect**. E.g. *If I hadn't eaten so much, I wouldn't have felt sick.* ( http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/third-conditional.html )

"*Did*" and "*didn't"* are simple past tense forms.  They aren't perfects.

If you write "*If I didn't give it to you*" (**simple past**: negation of "If I gave it to you"), then the main clause has to use the **conditional** (*not* the conditional perfect): "*walking the streets at night would be scary*".  (Second conditional.)

If you had written "*If I hadn't given it to you*" (**past perfect**), then the main clause would have used the **conditional perfect**: "*walking the streets at night would have been scary*".

In your example, the second conditional, "If I didn't give it to you, then walking the streets at night would be scary", seems the more natural set of forms to use.